# Twig Multiplication between two decimal values

Tags: symfony, twig

How can I multiple two decimal values in twig ?

Let's say var1 = "37.57" and var2 = "8" and I tried with

```
{{ var1 * var2 }}
```

But it multiplies only the integer value while ignoring the decimal it returns "296" which is 37 * 8.

Comment: are you sure the variable are right in the twig, try {{ dump(var1, var2) }} to make sure you've got what you think

Comment: check here => http://twigfiddle.com/yef16p. I recreated this and it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: This is what i see in dump 
     SimpleXMLElement {#962 ▼
      +"0": "72.75"
    }
    SimpleXMLElement {#960 ▼
      +"0": "20.35"
    }

in the twig 

    {{ (var1|number_format(2, ',', '.') * var2|number_format(2, ',', '.'))}}

It is still the same it multiple only the integral value

Comment: Okay I found that its taking those variables are string. how can i convert a string to integer value in twig??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it working.

For some reason the twig is considering it as a "string" instead of "interger" not sure why it is, since i simple return the data that i receive through external API connection.

here is the thing which worked for me:

```
{% set var_1 = 0 + var1|numberformat(2,'.',',') %}
{% set var_2 = 0 + var2|numberformat(2,'.',',') %}
```

then,

```
{{ (var_1 * var_2)|numberformat(2,'.',',')}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with

`{{ var1|number_format * var2|number_format }}`

Maybe it doesn't work because of string format *(even if string format should work)*.

Doc for [number_format](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/filters/number_format.html)

Answer (score 1):

The integer result may be produced if wrong decimal separator is used.